# Open image file with Python give Permission Denied error message

Tags: permissions, python

I am new to Linux but not Python. I am trying to migrate my Python skills to Linux.  With Windows I can open an image file with the default viewer using.

```
import os
os.system(r"C:\gTemp\Capture.JPG")
```

Using a valid Linux path the same code returns 'Permission denied'

```
import os
os.system(/home/myname/Capture.JPG")
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?
I am using 16.04 with Python 2.7

Comment: Invalid path? 'C:' has no meaning in Linux.

Comment: JPEG files aren't executable by themselves, and the system doesn't know what application you want to use to open therm: perhaps you should be using something like `system("xdg-open /home/myname/Capture.JPG")` - or (probably better) use `subprocess.call` as described here: [How to open a file with the standard application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1679895/4440445)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.system() executes the command that is passed to it. An image is not a command. Windows may execute an app to open the image, but that is Windows specific. The subprocess.call is your best bet as mentioned by steeldriver.